# Can't login when switching to TTY1

Tags: 12.04, tty

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  When I switch to the first text terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I'm presented with a prompt that asks for user name and password.  When I input the user name and password, I get login incorrect.  I'm typing the right user name and password.  What could be the problem?

Here is the [output](http://pastebin.com/4RzZiMH5) of `dmesg`

Here is the [/var/log/auth.log](http://pastebin.com/Lggseu2Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how the problem fixed it self.  I was using the system, and update manager came up telling me that there are updates available for my machine, so I looked  at the updates, and applied them.  One of those updates was a Kernel update.

So I don't know if that what fixed it or not, but is got fixed right after the updates were applied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a different keyboard layout? This is the only thing I can think of. Try typing some of the special characters from your password as the user name to test whether what you type is actually what you want.

Also, run

```
dmesg
```

from the terminal; the login failure should be seen in the system logs and maybe there is some additional explanation.

Comment: keyboard layout is OK.